# Laser printer - blurred / fringed edges (Kyocera EP C170n)

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer

I'm trying to restore print quality on my Kyocera EP C170n but am having no luck. The problem is that any hard edge is blurred / fringed with a fuzzy gray outline. This is particularly noticeable on text, as the gray fringing has the effect of "coloring in" the center of curved characters like the letter O. I've followed the manual to clean the chargers (wire, grid, lens) and the paper transfer unit (registration roller). I've also run the developer and drum cleaning cycles. None of these had any effect on the print quality. An example of the output is below. I also haven't found any articles online that describe the symptoms I'm seeing. Has anyone else seen this behavior before and if so, is there any way to fix it or do I just need to replace a piece (or given the age of this printer, potentially the whole device)?

[Example of printer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v56BB.jpg)

[Closeup of text with gray fringing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPK6h.jpg)